# Autodesk Viewer RenderProxy vb getting NaN

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to get geometry information from vb array in RenderProxy.Geometry. However, some elements in the array are returning NaN. How should I deal with this?
The model is translated from a Revit .rvt file, and the mesh I'm trying to get geometry is a surface in Revit.
Below is the screenshot of the vb array I'm talking about.
Thank you guys very much for any help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The geometry data in the "render proxy" mesh is available under `mesh.geometry`. To parse it, you'd need to learn more about the `THREE.BufferGeometry` class, but in short, the triangle positions could be parsed with something like this:

```js
function enumerateTriangles(model, dbid) {
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
        const mesh = frags.getVizmesh(fragid); // Obtain the THREE.Mesh object
        const indexBuffer = mesh.geometry.ib; // Typically Uint16Array in Forge
        const vertexBuffer = mesh.geometry.vb; // Typically Float32Array in Forge
        const positionItemOffset = mesh.geometry.attributes['position'].itemOffset; // The vertex buffer may contain other data in vertex buffer, not just positions
        for (let i = 0; i < indexBuffer.length; i += 3) {
            const i1 = indexBuffer[i];
            const i2 = indexBuffer[i + 1];
            const i3 = indexBuffer[i + 2];
            const p1 = new THREE.Vector3(vertexBuffer[i1 + positionItemOffset], vertexBuffer[i1 + positionItemOffset + 1], vertexBuffer[i1 + positionItemOffset + 2]);
            const p2 = new THREE.Vector3(vertexBuffer[i2 + positionItemOffset], vertexBuffer[i2 + positionItemOffset + 1], vertexBuffer[i2 + positionItemOffset + 2]);
            const p3 = new THREE.Vector3(vertexBuffer[i3 + positionItemOffset], vertexBuffer[i3 + positionItemOffset + 1], vertexBuffer[i3 + positionItemOffset + 2]);
            console.log('Triangle has vertices', p1, p2, p3);
        }
    }, true);
}
```